# HTML Agility Pack xpath expression assistance

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

I have html like the following:

```
<table width="98%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2">
<tr>
    <td height="20" colspan="2">
        &nbsp;
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td height="20" colspan="2" class="fontDestaque2NegritoHome">
        MATR&Iacute;CULA: PPAAG
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right" valign="middle" class="tx_bd">
        &nbsp;
    </td>
    <td align="right" valign="middle" class="tx_bd">
        &nbsp;
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="35%" align="right" valign="middle" class="tx_bd">
        <div align="left">
            <span class="tx_bold">Fabricante:</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td width="59%" align="right" valign="middle" class="tx_bd">
        <div align="left">
            CESSNA AIRCRAFT</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right" valign="middle" class="tx_bd">
        <div align="left">
            <span class="tx_bold">Modelo:</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td align="right" valign="middle" class="tx_bd">
        <div align="left">
            T206H</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right" valign="middle" class="tx_bd">
        <div align="left">
            <span class="tx_bold">N&uacute;mero de S&eacute;rie:</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td align="right" valign="middle" class="tx_bd">
        <div align="left">
            T20608735</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right" valign="middle" class="tx_bd">
        <div align="left" class="tx_bold">
            Tipo ICAO :
        </div>
    </td>
    <td align="right" valign="middle" class="tx_bd">
        <div align="left">
            C206</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right" valign="middle" class="tx_bd">
        <div align="left">
            <span class="tx_bold">Tipo de Habilita&ccedil;&atilde;o para Pilotos:</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td align="right" valign="middle" class="tx_bd">
        <div align="left">
            MNTE</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right" valign="middle" class="tx_bd">
        <div align="left">
            <span class="tx_bold">Classe da Aeronave:</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td align="right" valign="middle" class="tx_bd">
        <div align="left">
            POUSO CONVECIONAL 1 MOTOR CONVENCIONAL</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right" valign="middle" class="tx_bd">
        <div align="left">
            <span class="tx_bold">Peso M&aacute;ximo de Decolagem:</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td align="right" valign="middle" class="tx_bd">
        <div align="left">
            1633 - Kg</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right" valign="middle" class="tx_bd">
        <div align="left">
            <span class="tx_bold">N&uacute;mero M&aacute;ximo de Passageiros:</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td align="right" valign="middle" class="tx_bd">
        <div align="left">
            005</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="right" valign="middle" class="tx_bd">
        <div align="left">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="right" valign="middle" background="../images/bgPontilhado.gif"
        class="tx_bd">
        <div align="left">
            <img src="../images/bgPontilhado.gif" width="4" height="1"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="right" valign="middle" class="tx_bd">
        <div align="left">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right" valign="middle" class="tx_bd">
        <div align="left">
            <span class="tx_bold">Categoria de Registro:</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td align="right" valign="middle" class="tx_bd">
        <div align="left">
            PRIVADA SERVICO AEREO PRIVADOS</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right" valign="middle" class="tx_bd">
        <div align="left">
            <span class="tx_bold">N&uacute;mero dos Certificados (CM - CA)</span>:
        </div>
    </td>
    <td align="right" valign="middle" class="tx_bd">
        <div align="left">
            19040</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right" valign="middle" class="tx_bd">
        <div align="left">
            <span class="tx_bold">Situa&ccedil;&atilde;o no RAB:</span><span class="stop_litle">
            </span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td align="right" valign="middle" class="tx_bd">
        <div align="left">
            <span class="fontRed">ARRENDAMENTO OPERACIONAL/ALIENACAO FIDUCIARIA</span></div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right" valign="middle" class="tx_bd">
        <div align="left">
            <span class="tx_bold">Data da Compra/Transfer&ecirc;ncia:</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td align="right" valign="middle" class="tx_bd">
        <div align="left">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="right" valign="middle" class="tx_bd">
        <div align="left">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="right" valign="middle" background="../images/bgPontilhado.gif"
        class="tx_bd">
        <div align="left">
            <img src="../images/bgPontilhado.gif" width="4" height="1"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="right" valign="middle" class="tx_bd">
        <div align="left">
        </div>
    </td>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" valign="middle" class="tx_bd">
            <div align="left">
                <span class="tx_bold">Data de Validade do CA: </span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td width="3%" align="right" valign="middle" class="tx_bd">
            <div align="left">
                <span class="tx_bd">21/05/16</span></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right" valign="middle" class="tx_bd">
        <div align="left" class="tx_bold">
            <div align="left">
                Data de Validade da IAM:
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td align="right" valign="middle" class="tx_bd">
        <div align="left">
            <span class="tx_bd">110513</span></div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td height="18" align="right" valign="middle" class="tx_bd">
        <div align="left">
            <span class="tx_bold">Situa&ccedil;&atilde;o de Aeronavegabilidade:</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td height="18" align="right" valign="middle" class="tx_bd">
        <div align="left">
            Normal</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td height="18" colspan="2" align="right" valign="middle" class="tx_bd">
        <div align="left" class="tx_bold">
            Motivo(s):
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td height="18" colspan="2" align="right" valign="middle" class="tx_bd">
        <div align="left">
            <blockquote>
                <p>
                    <span class="tx_bold"></span>
                </p>
            </blockquote>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td height="18" colspan="2" align="left" valign="middle" class="tx_bd">
        Consulta realizada em: 16/8/2012 15:52:45<br>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to grab the following text:

- Cessna Aircraft
- T206H
- T20608735
- C206
- MNTE
- POUSO CONVECIONAL 1 MOTOR CONVENCIONAL
- 1633 - Kg
- 005
- PRIVADA SERVICO AEREO PRIVADOS
- 19040
- ARRENDAMENTO OPERACIONAL/ALIENACAO FIDUCIARIA
- 21/05/16
- 110513
- Normal

Some of the div's just contain the text I need. Other div's contain a span that contains the text I need. How would I construct the xpath for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use**:

```
//tr/td[@align='right' and @valign='middle' and @class='tx_bd']
       /div[@align='left 'and not(*)]
         /text()
```

Comment: I get a null reference exception so I will update my original post with the html document I'm searching, not just that snippet.

Comment: @SFAgitator, The XPath expression (regardless on what XML document it is evaluated), cannot be the cause for a null reference exception -- the problem is elsewhere in your code.

Comment: I was under the assumption that a NRE could be caused by the expression not finding a match in the document. I'll look through the code again.

Comment: @SFAgitator, No, if no node is selected, the evaluation result is an empty nodelist -- not an exception. If the code then tries to get an item from the empty node-list -- *this* may result in exception.

Comment: I should clarify - you're correct. Because I'm just testing for now, I'm not catching any errors, and in fact, I am trying to get an item from the empty(null) list. Below, the data variable is null when I run the code: var data = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr/td[@align='right' and @valign='middle' and @class='tx_bd']/div[@align='left 'and not(*)]/text()");

Comment: The NRE was indeed a problem elsewhere. Your xpath above worked wonderfully. Now I'm working through the anomolies in the html. Thank you very much @Dimitre - I really appreciate it.